# how to plot the linear regression in R?

Tags: r, linear-regression

I want to make the following case of linear regression in R

```
year<-rep(2008:2010,each=4)
quarter<-rep(1:4,3)
cpi<-c(162.2,164.6,166.5,166.0,166.4,167.0,168.6,169.5,170.0,172.0,173.3,174.0)
plot(cpi,xaxt="n",ylab="CPI",xlab="")
axis(1,labels=paste(year,quarter,sep="C"),at=1:12,las=3)
fit<-lm(cpi~year+quarter)
```

I want to plot the line that shows the linear regression of the data that I process. I have tried with:

```
abline(fit)
abline(fit$coefficients[[1]],c(fit$coefficients[[2]],fit$coefficients[[3]]))
```

The problem is that my formula is of the form:

```
y=a+b*year+c*quarter
```

and not something simpler like:

```
y=a+b*year
```

so how I can draw that line that shows the linear regression?

Is it possible to draw the line with abline?

Comment: With multiple regression coefficients, the regression does not represent a line.  Perhaps you want stats::decompose.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you looking for the `predict` function?

E.g.: using `lines(predict(fit))` will give:

[image]

You could also use this for predicting future data aligning with the calculated coefficients. E.g.

```
# plot the existing data with space for the predicted line
plot(c(cpi,rep(NA,12)),xaxt="n",ylab="CPI",xlab="",ylim=c(162,190))

# plot the future predictions as a line using the next 3 year periods
lines(13:24,
      predict(
        fit,
        newdata=data.frame(year=rep(c(2011,2012,2013),each=4),quarter=rep(1:4,3))
             )
     )

year<-rep(2008:2013,each=4)
axis(1,labels=paste(year,quarter,sep="C"),at=1:24,las=3)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks @thelatemail, but can you tell me why it does not work abline(a=0,b=1)?

Comment: There is no straight line for the predictions.

Comment: yes, you are right @DWin, I recognize my mistake it is a polynomial model so that is why there is no straight line, my bad

Answer (score 6):

```
cpi<-c(162.2,164.6,166.5,166.0,166.4,167.0,168.6,169.5,170.0,172.0,173.3,174.0)
cpits <- ts(cpi, start=2008, frequency=4)
plot(decompose(cpits))
```

[image]

Comment: This is the "right" answer. The notion that year and quarter are "independent" is mistaken (one might even say ridiculous).

Comment: @Dwin - could you explain that a bit more? Couldn't you have a scenario with temperature increasing overall in a linear fashion but fluctuating temperatures with each season? Would this make my `predict` based answer not statistically valid? Maybe I'm missing the point you are making.

Comment: you are right @thelatemail, this example was taken from a book that considers the fluctuation of the consumer price index by year and inside each year by quarters

Answer (score 6):

Humbug. These are all reasonable solutions, but they don't do what you ask for. Now what you ask for is slightly cooler and completely impractical, but can be done using `rgl`.

```
f <- function(x, y, coefs){
  z <- coefs[1] + coefs[2] * x + coefs[3] * y
  z
}

x <- seq(from=min(year), to=max(year), length.out=100)
y <- seq(from=min(quarter), to=max(quarter), length.out=100)

z <- outer(x, y, f, coefs=coef(fit))
```

Now where the magic happens in `rgl`:

```
library(rgl)

persp3d(x, y, z, col="lightblue")
```

[image]

It isn't done justice here, but it's pretty and you can move it about.

And what the hell, let's add your original points

```
points3d(year, quarter, cpi, size=5, col="red")
```

[image]

Comment: I never really liked 3D graphs in terms of readability, but have a +1 for explicitly answering the question.

Comment: @thelatemail They're much more readable if you actually use the rgl device and move the figure around. Luke Tierney has written [something on how to embed dynamic graphs into pdfs](http://www.stat.uiowa.edu/~luke/R/misc3d/misc3d-pdf/), but I haven't tried it.

Comment: Humbug, indeed. Go ahead. Interpret that plane.

Comment: @DWin I never said it was practical. I did it for fun. In all seriousness though, you might discover that there are large residuals where both predictors are large. This is *definitely* not a publication graph but it could be useful for helping students conceptualise what happens with regression in higher dimensions and why it becomes basically impossible to plot the results of multiple linear regression on a conventional xy scatterplot.

Answer (score 3):

The error lies in the way you're data was formatted.  Here is another option:

```
year<-seq(from=2008,to=2010.75,by=.25)
cpi<-c(162.2,164.6,166.5,166.0,166.4,167.0,168.6,169.5,170.0,172.0,173.3,174.0)
df <- data.frame(year,cpi)
plot(df)+abline(lm(df$cpi~df$year))
```

[image]

Then you can reformat the axes labels if you like.

Comment: This ignores the quarter, and thus is not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

The `Predict.Plot` and `TkPredict` functions in the TeachingDemos package will plot the relationship between one of the predictors and the response variable conditioned on the values of the other predictors.  `Predict.Plot` makes it fairly simple to see multiple lines from different conditions while `TkPredict` lets you interactively change the values being conditioned on (and will produce the `Predict.Plot` code to recreate the current plot).

These functions are general for regression models on multiple predictors, but will not be as good as decompose for a time series.