# Three continuous Explanatory Variables Visualization in R

Tags: r, visualization

I have a dataset from which has three continuous explanatory variables and one dependent variable. I have created a linear regression model for this data by

```
data <- read.csv("data.csv")
datafilter <- subset(data, select = -c(Case)
linearmodel_int <- lm(data = datafilter, taste ~ H2S*Lactic*Acetic)
```

My issue is that I don't know how to visualize the predictions from the model against the raw data. Essentially I am unsure how to visualize three continuous explanatory variables.

P.s. The data was found from
https://www3.nd.edu/~busiforc/handouts/Data%20and%20Stories/multicollinearity/Cheese%20Taste/Cheddar%20Cheese%20Data.html

Comment: `plot(linearmodel_int)` and googling the plot terms is a good place to start.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to plot the linear regression in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14451782/how-to-plot-the-linear-regression-in-r)